# Excel Conditional formatting that highlights values depending on two rules

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

i have four columns that are simplified and look like this

item    quantity        item    quantity

102 ---     1         ---             102   --(-3)

103  ---   1            ---            104  --(-1)

105 --- 1             ---   105--    (-1)

i want excel to highlight 104 in the third column because it does not exist in the first column, and i also want excel to highlight 102 in the third column because even though it exists in the first column, the absolute value of the number corresponding to it is higher than the corresponding value of 102 in the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two formulas are:

To find if it does not exist in the first column:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,C1)=0
```

Then to find if the absolute vlue is greater:

```
=ABS(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE),0))<ABS(D1)
```

So to get a rule that will color both the same color combine them with an `OR`:

```
=OR(ABS(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:B,2,FALSE),0))<ABS(D1),COUNTIF(A:A,C1)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: your solution was more than valuable, but i failed to mention that i would like the formula to account for multiple occurrences. For example, your formula only compares the first 102 value in column B2 with D3, What i would like is that if 102 occurs twice each with a value of 1 and 4, the formula would not highlight D1 because even though it is higher than one of them, it is less than the other.